# Codeigniter - Stop escape in function "from" of Query Builder

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, model, query-builder

I have a problem with the way of escape of Query Builder in Codeigniter 3.0.
For example, this code

```
echo $this->db->select('ROUND(3.456, 1) AS T1')->get_compiled_select();
```

Return:

> SELECT ROUND(3.456, **`1)`** AS `T1`

The function put backticks after a coma, but this is solved by setting FALSE the second parameter. But the function "from" put always backticks:

```
echo $this->nm->db->from('(SELECT ROUND(3.456, 1)) AS T1')->get_compiled_select()
```

Return:

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROUND(3.456, **`1))`** AS `T1`

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0. The problem exists since Codeigniter 2.2. I need use the Query Builder beacuse it's very easy to use, but its escape method is troublesome. How stop the escaping in the function from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

or you can disable on current query and enable it again rather on whole app. Before query, insert

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
```

and after query, set to TRUE to enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure use it. In "database.php" file should be added a new element for the config array of database connection.

```
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers'] = FALSE;
```

That code disable the escape mode. But is it advisable? What is the risk of disabling the escaping system?

Thanks.

Comment: or you can disable on current query and enable it again rather on whole app